# How to write a Bash script which queries a PostgreSQL on another physical server

Tags: database, bash, postgresql

I would like to create a Bash script, say queryserver.sh, that resides on ComputerA at IP 192.168.2.1, with USERA and password PASSA and queries a Postgresql database on ComputerB at IP 192.160.10.1 with user USERB and password PASSB for example.

In short, ComputerB has a PostgreSQL database table whose data is used to update a Postgresql table on ComputerA. ComputerA hosts the database used for a web application whereas ComputerB hosts backend number crunching functionalities.

In Microsoft SQL server, there is a concept of linked server, but I couldn't find the same concept on PostgreSQL.

Are there better ways than to use a Bash script and remotely invoke it using C++ CORBA?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this problem. `psql` can connect to remote hosts. You could also use `ssh` to run `psql` remotely. But since you referenced MSSQL's linked servers, the most comparable in PostgreSQL is the [Foreign Data Wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html).

To allow USERA on ComputerA's PostgreSQL instance to access tables on ComputerB as USERB:

```
CREATE SERVER ComputerB
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (host '192.160.10.1', port '5432', dbname 'computerB');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR USERA
        SERVER ComputerB
        OPTIONS (user 'USERB', password 'PASSB');
```

Then you need to use `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` for each table you'd like to use.